# Error:No resource identifier found for attribute 'lable' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-studio

when i try to add splash screen in my app then i found this error massage. i found this error in Splashscreen.java, i tryed to search in many place but cant find the ans, here is my code please help me guys.
thanks in advance.
here is the error result picture https://gyazo.com/3ac877d4dc8cccee1607411c00d81ccc

```
package club.moviestreet.www.moviestreet;

import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.widget.ImageView;

        import club.moviestreet.www.moviestreet.MainActivity;

        import java.util.Random;


public class Splashscreen extends Activity {

    Thread splashTread;
    ImageView imageView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splashscreen);
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        int[] ids = new int[]{R.drawable.s_img,R.drawable.s_image_black, R.drawable.s_image_black2};
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int r= randomGenerator.nextInt(ids.length);
        this.imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(ids[r]));

        splashTread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    int waited = 0;
                    // Splash screen pause time
                    while (waited < 3500) {
                        sleep(100);
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Splashscreen.this,
                            MainActivity.class);
                    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    Splashscreen.this.finish();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // do nothing
                } finally {
                    Splashscreen.this.finish();
                }

            }
        };
        splashTread.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: Add manifest entry of Splashscreen .

Comment: how to do it sir? as i dont know about it

Comment: I have added a answer below see if it workout for you .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thing you are using `android:lable` in your manifest.

There is no `android:lable` the attribute is `android:label`.

just replace **android:lable** by **`android:label**